# data transfer from mobile app to computer

Tags: android, ios, data-transfer

I am working on a simple program that collects data from the field on an android app and stores it in a database.  The next step for me is to be able to take the data from the collected and transfer it to a programming running on a computer.  I am looking for best suggestions on this.  One aspect of my field data collection is that I want it to be scale-able, right now it is only for android, but in the future I would like an apple version.  I have looked at tethering and transferring data over USB, however from what I have read android has issues with that, and I am not sure how easy it is for an apple product.  The other option that I have found is using a dedicated web server.  Download from the mobile app and then upload to the computer program.
Is one option better then another, have I missed an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sync your database to a computer. Instead, sync it to the cloud using something like Google App Engine. The APIs are easier, and the result is more useful besides.

Comment: Just because they are in the "cloud" doesn't make them not computers. I assure there is still a physical computer at the other end of the magic =p. You raise a very good point though.

Comment: That was my general idea, to use a cloud base system.  I was just wondering if there were any ideas that I was missing.  Thank you for confirming my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that adb is installed on the host computer, then you can just use batch scripts to grab the necessary data from the android device.

For example, have your android app save its data on the sdcard in a file called fielddata.txt

Then you can have a script:

```
adb pull /sdcard/fielddata.txt fielddata.txt
```